# SOQL - Select only contacts that have related Opportunities

Tags: soql, opportunity, contact

I have the following SOQL:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunities) FROM Contact WHERE Email = 'test@test.com'
```

I want to restrict this to return only those contacts for which the related Opportunities list is not empty. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good place to apply a [semi-join](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm#semijoin_and_antijoin) pattern, which is the most common query tool used to limit a query by the *presence or absence* of related objects. It is made only a little bit more complex here by the fact that Opportunity and Contact are related by a sort of junction object, OpportunityContactRole:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunities) 
FROM Contact 
WHERE Email = 'test@test.com'
      AND Id IN (SELECT ContactId
                 FROM OpportunityContactRole)
```